# io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: GET Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, grpc, http2

I am getting Unexpected HTTP/1.x request with curl command (ver 7.77.0) curl -k -v --http2 http://localhost:9090/v1/grpc/hello request

and

HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes on  curl -k -v --http2 https://localhost:9090/v1/grpc/hello request

https://github.com/konzerntech/grpcsample/issues/1

I am working spring boot GRPC application, trying to hit GET HTTP request from curl

below is my proto file service method

---

```
service PingPongService {
    rpc ping(PingRequest) returns (PongResponse) {
    
    option (google.api.http) = { get: "/v1/grpc/{ping}" };
    }
}
```

My intention is to access grpc stub method through a json request. Any help
the whole code is shared in git hub.

Comment: what is the request?

Comment: curl -k -v --http2 http://localhost:9090/v1/grpc/hello
curl -k -v --http2 https://localhost:9090/v1/grpc/hello

Comment: What was the reason ? @Konzern